# Unable to convert file in byte array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

i have an issue when i am trying to convert a file into byte array using this code

```
var fileByte = new byte[pic.ContentLength];
```

it converts the file but when file is uploaded it is corrupted.
and when i tried the another code to convert the file i.e

```
   var pic = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["ImagePath"];
   byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pic.FileName);
```

it thrown an exception like

> Could not find file 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\slide2.jpg'.

after words i'd tried for this

```
byte[] b = StreamFile(pic.FileName);

private byte[] StreamFile(string filename)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        Create a byte array of file stream length
        byte[] ImageData = new byte[fs.Length];

        //Read block of bytes from stream into the byte array
        fs.Read(ImageData, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));

        //Close the File Stream
        fs.Close();
        return ImageData; //return the byte data
    }
```

but it also throw and exception like

> Could not find file 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\slide2.jpg'.

Comment: *head scratching* - As the exception tells you, there is no file. No file means no conversion to byte array. Check first with `System.IO.File.Exists(pic.FileName);` if you file is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First line of code doesn't convert file to byte array, it just creates a byte array with size of `pic.ContentLength`.

Second example throws you an exception which clearly states that you don't have the image on specified path (defined by `pic.FileName`).

To solve this, you should work with the request's file `Stream` and write it into byte array.

```
var pic = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["ImagePath"];
byte[] bytes;
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
   pic.InputStream.CopyTo(stream);
   bytes = stream.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: do you have any link please ?